# When to use “that” and when to use “which”, especially in relative clauses

Tags: pronouns, conjunctions, relative-clauses, which-that, relative-pronouns

When is it appropriate to use *that* as opposed to *which* with relative clauses?

Comment: I heard a story once about someone copy-editing something by Alfred Tarski. They had switched every occurrence of "that" and "which", since they considered that Tarski had got them completely the wrong way round. Tarski sent back the manuscript with all the occurrences of "that" and "which" swapped back again.

Comment: I am a native speaker and I confess I don't know either; the only time I ever notice it is when using a certain Microsoft product, and I always do what it suggests just to get rid of those damned green squiggles.

Comment: @Brian Hooper: This is precisely why I turn off the grammar checking in Word. I still write however I want, but it bothers me that a software program doesn't approve. I guess that's one definition of neurosis.

Comment: Wish I could up-vote the question twice; this is something that always gets me as well, and I never seem to remember the rules governing the use of the two words.

Comment: this made me think of, "That which does not kill me makes me stronger"

Comment: My GMAT instructor and the Oxford guide to english grammar, along with me, agrees to what you think as right. "That" is used if the modifier is Essential and it is used without commas. For example: the mansion that is painted red is mine.
"Which" is used if the modifier is non-essential and with a comma. Like in "This mansion, which has been painted red, is mine."

In everyday conversations "that" and "which" are interchangeable.

Comment: No, unfortunately this is a myth promulgated by awful books and then sometimes repeated by EFL teachers ...

Comment: @vickyace Can you give us the quote from the Oxford book along with its title, please?

Comment: @Drew On the contrary, that post is about using *that* in NON-defining relative clauses. This question is entirely about defining relative clauses.

Comment: @vickyace I don't think that anyone disputes that *which* is used in non-defining relative clauses, or, indeed, that *that* is used in defining ones. But can you give us a quote where it says that *which* is NOT used in *defining* relative clauses?

Comment: I said that the books agree to what he thinks, not that they lay down a law! They're flexible, just like you described vividly. I don't remember the book but I think it mentioned John Eastwood. 

There are many angles though. You could say "the town in which she lived" or "the town that she lived in." Both are correct. There are subtleties to consider that matter while we construct something. You're absolutely right.

Comment: @vickyace Absolutely agree, you can use both, and can choose the one that suits your own needs and style. Good, isn't it! :)

Comment: I use a "that" clause without commas for important information that cannot be omitted.  For unimportant information, which can be omitted,  I will use a "which" clause with commas.

Comment: Word 2013 suggests that "which" be used (with a preceding comma) when the following phrase is not crucial to the meaning of the sentence. Consider: *The car that was red sped past.* vs. *The car, which was red, sped past.* The first one is more likely to support the "theory" that red cars are faster than cars of any other colour, whereas the second is just describing the car.

Comment: As my old editor put it much more simply: "When it matters, that defines; which explains." Elswhere the two do often appear interchangeable but try swapping them in a sentence such as: "That is the one for which we’re looking", even if it is reduced to "That is the one we’re looking for".

Comment: @DogLover In my opinion there is a difference between "... the car that was red..." and "...the car, which was red,..." The first form implies that the car has been described previously (eg by saying "There were four cars in the race, one black, two white, and one red."). The second form adds description to a car which has been described previously.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

*That* and *which* are interchangeable when introducing integrated relative clauses. Although some grammar mavens (i.e., people who hold forth on such topics but know little or nothing about linguistics) and copy editors will insist otherwise, the rule is completely bogus.

See, for instance, [Language Log on *that* vs *which*](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001461.html), written by the co-editor of The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language.

Practically speaking, it is not something that any normal person will generally notice or follow in spoken English and it's frequently — and rightly — ignored even in literary writing. So even from that point of view it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: Three cheers for Language Log!

Comment: Thanks for the link and the answer.  I had been wondering about the distinction some people claim (but I had never learned in English classes), and your answer allowed me to understand the issue better.

Comment: A year later, but still in Hogswatchtide, on New Year's Eve, I'll add my [Xmas 1995 post](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html) on _that_ vs _which_ (though this is pre-CGEL, so I used _Restrictive_ and _Non-Restrictive_ instead of Geoff's _integrated_ and whatever the other one was. (I use McCawley, myself; one can actually lift it with one hand)

Comment: @AlanHogue you say "that and which are interchangeable when introducing integrative relative clauses". But when are they not interchangeable (if ever)?

Comment: -1, I hate this answer.  There is a difference between *that* and *which* in that the latter is nonrestrictive.

Comment: @Jez: There is a difference between _that_ and _which_ in that the latter may be used grammatically to mark a nonrestrictive relative clause, and the former may not. In restrictive clauses, of course, both are grammatical.

Comment: -1 The most useful information here would surely be that ***that** *CAN'T* be used in non-defining clauses!!! (you edit it and I'll upvote it!)

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Your position is logical. The trouble is that the word *that* serves so many roles in English (and even in this very comment!) that the word *which* makes a welcome change. Though I am of the conservative, antique school which (that?) holds that language is fundamentally nondemocratic, that proper English is solely that which ("that which"!) the best writers have endorsed and confirmed through decades of usage, even I can admit defeat on a logical point like this one. I fear that the answerer is right. As a conjunctive pronoun in this sense, *which* may stand in place of *that.*

Comment: In the spoken language this answer is correct.  Grammatical conventions are easily overriden by vocal inflections or facial expressions.  When neither vocal inflections nor facial expressions are available, which is the case with this comment, a writer that knows the rules can be effective. Effectiveness is hampered slightly, that does not bother some people, when ignoring grammar rules which are minor.

Comment: It is surprising to me that this answer is marked as correct and is the most upvoted answer. This answer is biased as it is based on a single unauthoritative source. It also claims other opinions "bogus", which is a biased word used to attack the *people* who hold a different opinion (in addition to the opinion itself). See my answer below with better citations.

Comment: By "integrated relative clauses" do you mean restrictive clause or non-restrictive clause?

Comment: @user963241 "Integrated relative clause" is the CGEL terminology for "restrictive relative clause". They're integrated because there's no comma, get it? I forget what they call non-restrictive relative clauses, but somebody will remind us.

Comment: Just FYI: In ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (E) "that is" is used 200 times and "which is" is used 145 times.

Answer (score 66):

Well, the difference is slight but real. According to the New Oxford American Dictionary:

> In U.S. English, it is usually recommended that **which** be employed only for nonrestrictive (or nonessential) clauses: *the horse, which is in the paddock, is six years old* (the *which* clause contains a nonessential fact, noted in passing; the horse would be six years old wherever it was). A *that* clause is restrictive (or essential), as it identifies a particular thing: *the horse that is in the paddock is six years old* (not any horse, but the one in the paddock).

Note also that the word *that* can be omitted where it introduces a subordinate clause:

> He said he was coming. *[He said that he was coming.]*

But it is required when it is the subject of the clause:

> The family that plays together stays together.

More usage notes from NOAD:

> Is there any difference between the use of **that** and **which** in sentences such as *any book that gets children reading is worth having*, and *any book which gets children reading is worth having?* The general rule is that, in restrictive relative clauses, where the relative clause serves to define or restrict the reference to the particular one described, **that** is the preferred relative pronoun. However, in nonrestrictive relative clauses, where the relative clause serves only to give additional information, **which** must be used: *this book, which is set in the last century, is very popular with teenagers*, but not *this book, that is set in the last century, is very popular with teenagers*.

Comment: which of the following would be right? or do they have different meanings?

1. Use the interface that provides access.
2. Use the interface which provides access.

Comment: @Lea: #1 urges you to use whichever interface provides access. #2 says the interface in question does provide access. Also, #2 should have a comma after interface to make clear that you don't mean it in the restrictive, relative sense.

Comment: simplest way for me to remember this is: use "which" to tell *that*; use "that" to tell *which*. In other words, use "which" to provide additional (non-essential) information, and use "that" to specify *which one*.

Comment: It's useful to distinguish British from American usage, here.  The OED considers them "equally correct" for restrictive relative clauses http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/that-or-which.  Being an American, I prefer the finer distinctions afforded by the NOAD in this answer.

Comment: I personally tend to disagree with this answer's conclusion (though I am American), but the conclusion is well argued and well supported. +1

Comment: @Robusto— But it is required when it is the subject of the clause: _The family that plays together stays together._ But we don't need a "that" in _The horse raced past the barn fell_, do we?

Comment: @user405662: In my view, you do need a *that* in "The horse [that] raced past the barn fell."

Comment: Thank you, Sir @Robusto. But the sentence could also be interpreted as _The horse [that was] raced past the barn fell, right? Which makes it a garden-path sentence.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind could you please recommend some good literature/material on the figures of speech? I've gone through some of the questions on this here, and believe that's one of your specialities. :)

Answer (score 26):

Actually, there's more to this than mentioned in some other answers. The word *that* is a subordinator; it is not a relative word like *who, where, when,* or *which.* Even in integrated relative clauses, they are not always interchangeable. When the relative construction follows a fronted preposition, only relative words will do, so relative pronoun *which* is available, but *that* isn't.

> *We have to protect the environment **in which** we live.*
>
> *No art can be properly understood apart from the culture **of which** it is a part.*

Conversely, when the relative clause is post-modifying superlatives, we can choose between *that* or no subordinator, but *which* is not possible:

> *He's **the best (that)** I've ever seen.*
>
> *He's **the fastest runner (that)** I've ever seen.*

Also in cleft sentences with prepositional phrases like the following, only *that* is available.

> *It wasn't **for you that** I bought it.*
>
> *It was **from John that** she heard the news.*

Finally, *which* usually cannot be used where other relative words would work, but *that* typically can:

> *They gave the prize to **the girl that** spoke first.*    [*who*]
>
> *He was to leave at **the time that** she arrived.*    [*when*]
>
> *They looked **every place that** she could be.*   [*where*]
>
> *That's not **the reason that** she resigned.* [*why*]
>
> *I like **the way that** she plays.*           [**how*]

Comment: A great way to explain the differences; the examples are the best I could ask to clarify the point.

Comment: I would say that for the last batch of examples, *which* would be marginally grammatical though awkward for me—more for some than others. It seems that *which* can substitute more easily for *when, where,* and *why* than for *who* and *how*

Comment: In today's enlightened times, even an inherently good answer on ELU is deemed sub-optimal without linked, attributed supporting reference/s.

Comment: *Way, reason, place* and *time* are all exceptional nouns which behave oddly when it comes to relative clauses **That's the restaurant that I met my wife* won't work even though its integrated and would be grammatical with *where*, for example.

Answer (score 18):

Generally, "that" goes with restrictive clauses - those where the information provided in the clause is necessary to identify the subject: "The beer that belongs to me" (as opposed to all other beers in the world).

"Which" goes with non-restrictive clauses - those which give information but which do not define the subject: "The beer, which was a little warm, was still tasty."

Comment: +1. But as the Language Log (or any sensible grammar book really) points out, "which" is also acceptable in restrictive clauses: "the beer which belongs to me" is fine. But it's definitely wrong to use "This beer, that was a still warm, was …".

Answer (score 15):

It's not the most authoritative/formal source ever, but the grammar book [*Woe is I*](http://books.google.com/books?id=oB3LkxTNHgcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Woe+is+I&hl=en&ei=15BbTKOeCY_EsAPUpNnhDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) provides an easily remembered rule of thumb that has stuck with me through the years:

> "Commas, which cut out the fat, go with which, never with that."

Comment: +1 for Woe is I, which is a great guide to "most grammar issues that still confuse well-educated people".  And because I *still* use this rhyme from it to remember this particular issue.

Comment: Yikes, that book doesn't know about "singular they"!? http://books.google.com/books?id=oB3LkxTNHgcC&lpg=PP1&dq=Woe%20is%20I&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 10):

In this particular case, either 'which' or 'that' is grammatical.

In *general*, 'which' and 'that' are interchangeable when referring to something inanimate.

The main restriction is that ***that* is not usually used to introduce a so-called "non-restrictive relative"** (essentially, relative clauses where a pause is obligatory between the relative clause and the surrounding sentence).

However, in your case, the relative clause is of the "restrictive" type and speakers would use either 'that' or 'which' fairly interchangeably.

Answer (score 6):

My answer comes so late that it is probably doomed to dwell at the bottom of the answer column, but the question remains a question about which I care, so my answer adds a point other answers have missed.

"Which" instead of ["that"](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/that-elusive-non-restrictive-that/) is almost always used in sentences with nonrestrictive qualification, as

> The horse, **which** is in the paddock, is six years old.

The horse would still be six years old even if it were in the stable, see? Alternately and more to the point, there seems to be no second horse in view; there is no four-year-old horse about that might (which might?) also concern us.

As other answers have noted and as NOAD has advised, American English slightly, abstractly prefers the word *which*—as a conjunctive pronoun—to be reserved for this nonrestrictive use.

However, the best American writers have not uniformly followed NOAD's advice. Peggy Noonan does indeed follow it (with no recent exception I have observed):

> My thought, **which** is really a question, is that candidates for president, while natural competitors, sometimes get to the point where they think they are going to win, and it messes with their heads.

John Steinbeck however does not:

> The mattresses **which** had been on the floor were gone.

Even if you are of the rigid, conservative, antidemocratic school of proper usage, as I tend to be, it is hard to argue with Steinbeck. Nor is Steinbeck the only one.

NOAD's advice, quoted in another answer, is fine as far as it goes. NOAD is correct. NOAD should be heeded. However, there is more to the story than NOAD tells.

The trouble with the conjunctive pronoun *that* is that *that* is not just a conjunctive pronoun. It is a word with too many uses for its own good—too many uses, even in this very paragraph. The word *that* is a word which (a word that?) serves so many roles, in various parts of English speech, that the less frequent word *which* makes a welcome change. In the usage of *which* versus *that,* the euphonic has trumped the strictly logical.

Germanic languages are sometimes like that. Can't help it. It's in the bones of the language. English is not like Greek.

In short, heed NOAD's advice by default, but where *which* sounds better than *that*—as in complex sentences it often does, and even sometimes in simple sentences like Steinbeck's—even if you are American, feel free to switch to *which.*

You may often find cause to switch.

Comment: @sumelic: If you have time, would make the suggested edits? I had not known that all languages are like that. In particular, I had thought that the peculiar usage of "das" and its cognates was a Germanic thing -- unlike, say, "qua," whose cognates are not used in such a way. But my Greek is not so good (as in, my Greek is practically nonexistent), so you may be right.

Comment: @sumelic: I like the changes, and find nothing further to add to them. You have been generous with your time. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[This is an important question because of all the folks visiting this site for guidance, who may well pass answers on to other students and writers. I myself in my pre-linguist days used to fall victim to this 'rule'. I have total sympathy for the Original Poster, as I do for my former self, and all literature, EFL students and authors who are confronted with this so-called grammar rule. GMAT students don't despair, just find which non-existent rule they're looking for now. It's quite good fun and not that difficult. Anyway here's my answer to the question...]

The idea that *which* is not used for restrictive clauses is a myth promulgated in the worst English grammar text-books and style guides ever written. The greatest writers in the English language have continuously used *which* as a relative pronoun in restrictive relative clauses — as has everyone else too.

Some info from the post [*Sidney Goldberg on NYT grammar: zero for three*](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001461.html), by Geoffrey Pullum, Professor of General Linguistics at the University of Edinburgh, co-author of the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (2002), shows how far through various books you would need to go before finding *which* appearing as a restrictive relative pronoun. The first number given in the list below shows the number of lines in the entire book. The second number shows on which line the author first used *which* as a relative pronoun in a restrictive relative clause:

> - A Christmas Carol (Dickens): 1,921 lines, first occurrence on line 217 = 11% of the way through;
> - Alice in Wonderland (Carroll): 1,618 lines, line 143 = 8%;
> - Dracula (Stoker): 9,824 lines, line 8 = less than 1%;
> - Lord Jim (Conrad): 8,045 lines, line 15 = 1%;
> - Moby Dick (Melville): 10,263 lines, line 103 = 1%;
> - Wuthering Heights (Bronte): 7,599 lines, line 56 = 0.736%...

Now, I know these authors are idiots who didn't know how to speak English properly, but just how did their editors and publishers get away with it? And all the people who decided to put these books on school syllabi? They, of course, should be shot.

Getting serious again: importantly, as Pullum also shows in the post [*A Rule Which Will Live in Infamy*](http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2012/12/07/a-rule-which-will-live-in-infamy/), there are situations when we, in fact, cannot use *that* for restrictive clauses and in which we have to use *which*. (Oh look one of them happened right there. I couldn't for example have written ... "and in *that* we have to use *which*"). Here are the three situations Geoff Pullum describes:

> - The putative ban can’t apply when a preposition precedes the relative pronoun: *The town in which she lived* is grammatical but **the town in that she lived* isn’t.
> - The supposed rule should be ignored when modifying demonstrative *that*, because *that which you prefer* is clearly preferable to ?*that that you prefer*.
> - The rule can’t apply to a conjoined which: *We must trust the unknown entity who or which created us* is grammatical but **We must trust the unknown entity who or that created us* isn’t.

Here is the passage in which (Oh no, there I go again with another one!) the famous quote that Pullum is playing with appears:

> “Yesterday, December 7, 1941—a date which will live in infamy—the United States of America was suddenly and deliberately attacked by naval and air forces of the Empire of Japan.” That was how President Franklin D. Roosevelt opened his famous infamy speech, 71 years ago. Ignoring the writing handbooks, he opened with a passive construction, which of course is just right for the rhetorical context (America as innocent victim). And he also ignored another bogeyman rule: He introduced a restrictive relative clause with *which*.

The answer to the OP's question, therefore, is that *which* can,  and sometimes must, be used for restrictive relative clauses. It's not a mistake to do so.

I leave you with Geoff Pullum's last words from the link above:

> Grammar snobs trying to show off their linguistic rectitude by playing gotcha with an invented rule that never matched educated usage; copy editors slaving away trying to enforce it; Microsoft Word blindly putting wavy green underlining under every relative *which* not preceded by a comma. What a senseless waste of time and energy.
>
> Follow the Fowler rule if you want to; it’s up to you. But don’t tell me that it’s crucial or that the best writers respect it. It’s a time-wasting early-20th-century fetish, a bogeyman rule undeserving of the attention of intelligent grownups.

Comment: I appreciate the time spent to post this answer and its detail. I'm curious about the apparent annoyance about my (seeming) misconception--it was just a question! The resources you picked seem particularly vitriolic about the topic. Also, I didn't find the use of *in which* to be compelling or clever--clearly, *in which* is restrictive, but I wasn't asking about it. Also, when *that* is not correct, *which* must obviously be used. My question was not about those cases.

Comment: @ErikE Sorry if it came across that I'm annoyed about your question. I'm not!! Really, really not! I think it's a very, very important question indeed, and I don't for one sec think there's anything wrong with having this idea per se. What does kind of make me mad though is that someone invented this rule, and it now affects language learners, writers, students, grammarians and GMAT sitters all over the globe, when the so-called grammar point never had any basis in the actual language! I don't understand what GMAT want people to use when they want need to say *the box in which its hidden ...*

Comment: @ErikE I've edited my post to show my actual feelings, and so that it's plain that I feel that your question (which I'd already upvoted) is important and worthy! Hope this comes across now :)

Comment: @ErikE Hmmm, if *which* is right in restrictive clauses when *that*'s wrong, why isn't it also right in restrictive clauses when *that*'s right?

Comment: I think saying "*Which* cannot be used in any restrictive sense" is patently false. It can be used, but with different constructions such as *in which* or *that which*. As a drop-in replacement for *that* (when used in its restrictive sense), it seems less apt to me.

Comment: Well, ok, but why do we need to look at it as a drop in replacement? Melville didn't ...

Comment: It's an artificial distinction that's not required--you're right. I had just spent several years thinking this way, so it's hard to break the habit. "I only eat chocolate chip cookies that my mother makes" is quite different from "I only eat chocolate chip cookies, which my mother makes." It's useful to have a restrictive word and a nonrestrictive word.

Comment: Yes,but not that different from *I only eat those chocolate chip cookies which my mother makes*. I'd say, if anything, that *which* sounds a bit too formal!

Comment: But if *which* can be restrictive, how you do succinctly say the latter, "I only eat chocolate chip cookies. My mother happens to make such things."?

Comment: @ErikE There are loads of situations where *that* might be preferred. The great thing about having both options (*that* and *which)* is you can choose the one that suits you best at that particular time! :)

Comment: @ErikE: the difference between restrictive *which* and non-restrictive *which* in speech is conveyed by intonation, stress, and whether there is a short pause before *which*. The difference in writing is conveyed by context and/or by a comma before a non-restrictive *which*. There's no need to restrict *which* to non-restrictive clauses, and this is a very confusing rule because it goes against the natural tendencies of several hundred million native English speakers, most of whom wouldn't be able to tell you what a non-restrictive clause was, even though they know intuitively.

Comment: @PeterShor, right you are!

Comment: You should repost this answer on the much older and much upvoted page https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which but then you've got to explain why you posted this comment [-1 The most useful information here would surely be that **that** *CAN'T be used in non-defining clauses!!!](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which#comment370839_96)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Mission accomplished.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think I can have seen that communication when you posted it, but what's wrong with the comment re *that*?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I don't think there's anything wrong with the comment you posted nearly nine years ago :) Sorry but I do not remember what motivated me to post the comment,  I do not remember the question nor the answers that were submitted and I'm sorry but I'm not going to try to catch up and read the content. It was a long time ago. I am older and I am tired. Forgive me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No probs. Aren't we all! (older) Just so long as there's nothing I need to address :)

Answer (score 1):

In British English usage the two are largely interchangeable, with the restrictive/non-restrictive distinction being indicated only by the presence or absence of a comma preceding the pronoun in question. This more often manifests itself as a restrictive "which" rather than a non-restrictive "that".

The only dissent that one may encounter in the UK tends to be a result of over-familiarity with the Americanish preferences of the Microsoft Word grammar checker, especially in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

I have always learned - and therefore taught - that the choice to use "that" or "which" in a restrictive/identifying clause is purely based on register.  "That" is used in an informal or spoken setting, whereas "which" is preferably used in more formal situations, for example in a formal report or essay.

"That" and "which" are therefore interchangeable in a restrictive clause, in my book.

Similarly, we can use "that" to refer to a person in informal, spoken register.  Here below are examples which are all grammatically correct but go from least to most formal.  The last two are probably outdated today.

The guy that I spoke to yesterday was French.

The guy who I spoke to yesterday was French.

The gentleman whom I spoke to yesterday was French.

The gentleman to whom I spoke yesterday was French.

As for usage in non-restrictive clauses, you can only use "which" with commas to mark the non-essential relative clause.

Comment: Register is probably part of it. However, I don't think there's a clear-cut gradient in usage based on register; obviously people who believe restrictive "which" is "grammatically incorrect" will not use it even in formal situations.

Answer (score 1):

The so-called American preference for banning "which" from restrictive relative clauses represents nothing more than the penetration of the educational system by Strunk and White's Elements of Style, which essentially invented the distinction where none could be demonstrated by even the most rudimentary statistical analysis.

http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497

Comment: You're saying that the influence was unwarranted. Nevertheless, influence it has been.

Answer (score 0):

At times it seems rather confusing about the appropriate usage of which and that (both are used for groups and/or things and never for person*s*, at least i cant think of any such situation).

I have a simple rule to use them,

*'That'* implements a ***Restrictive/Essential clause*** and *'which'* implements a ***Non-restrictive/Non-essential clause***.

In your example, the 1st sentence gives an idea that the particular class of motorcycles are already identified, hence, *which* begins a non-essential clause.

Comment: There's just one problem with your rule: native speakers don't actually use 'that' and 'which' in this way...!

Comment: @Downvoters:  Do you mind leaving a comment for voting down?!! I don't mind receiving down-votes when my answer is not good enough,  it will let the readers get a better information about a subject.  That's the reason I wouldn't delete an answer even if it has negative votes.

Comment: Reason for downvote (I suspect): Your answer was a duplicate of two previous answers and doesn't actually add anything new.

Comment: @PeterShor:  I originally answered to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68682/how-to-choose-between-which-and-that?lq=1) which was later merged here.  I doubt your reason for down-vote,  i got a down-vote before it was merged.  Thanks for taking time to read my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The literary examples that (not which) Pullum gives are from the 19th century. The farther you go back in American history, the more closely American literary language adheres to British usage, and British usage favors the use of which over that in the case in question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between *that* and *which*:

- **which** may be used grammatically to mark a nonrestrictive relative clause, and
- **that** may not.

In restrictive clauses, of course, both are grammatical.

John Lawler