# "Which" vs. "what" — what's the difference and when should you use one or the other?

Tags: differences, questions, determiners, which-what

Most of the time one or the other feels better, but every so often, "which" vs. "what" trips me up.

So, what's the exact difference and when should you use one or the other?

Comment: Related: [When is it appropriate to use 'that' as opposed to 'which'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-that-as-opposed-to-which)

Comment: There's also a very illustration on [pearsonlongman.com website](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00052.htm) I found useful.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

"Which" is more formal when asking a question that requires a choice between a number of items. You can use "What" if you want, though.

Generally speaking, you can replace the usage of "which" with "what" and be OK grammatically. It doesn't always work the other way around, however. There needs to be a context of choice. For example:

> *Which/What flavor of ice cream do you want?*
>
> - Either is fine, but "which" is better.
>
> *Which/What do you want for dessert?*
>
> - "Which" only works in the context of being presented with choices (e.g. a dessert cart right in front of you).

Comment: That's in questions. _Which_ and _what_ are also used in certain types of relative clauses, and their usage is not simple. So this is not a duplicate answer for any new question giving examples with non-question uses of _which_ and _what_.

Comment: I've never thought of this being a matter of formal vs informal.  Which holds out a promise of a choice between a list of items.  What simply demands that a choice be made with no promise of a list.  "What do you want, ice cream"?  Here you can't use "which".

Comment: What about the example of a phone number? There is a fixed set of possible phone numbers, but everyone uses "what" and it would sound unnatural to use "which."

Comment: I wouldn't say "Which flavour ice-cream do you want?", unless all the different flavours on offer were available to see, or listed, let's say, on a card - or the possible flavours were known to the person I was asking. If they nor I hadn't any idea what was available, I would say "What flavour do you want?" "Which", in a question, suggests that the available options are known.

Comment: @JeffGrimes we can guess which popular flavor of ice-cream is available even if we don't see them but we cannot really guess an entire phone number, I think that's why we never say "Which phone number is it?".

Answer (score 52):

Questions of attribute which and what: We usually use *which* when we are asking about a fixed or limited number of things or people, and *what* when we are not. Often, however, we can use either which or what with little difference in meaning. Compare:

- > What towns do we go through on the way?

  The speaker doesn't know the area.
- > Which towns do we go through on the way?

  The speaker knows the area and the towns in it.

If you mean when they are conjunctions, it is another question.

Comment: So the answer is that ultimately there are cases where there are no rules but you have to kinda know the connotations? Huh.

Comment: "Which are winter months in Europe?" or "What are winter months in Europe"?

Comment: @Peter It would be the former, since it's only a handful of months and you know it all.

Comment: Did any one add that while using which, the preceding clause has a comma after it unlike the case of what.