# Meaning of 'be much as'

Tags: meaning, phrases

> If aliens ever visit us, I think the outcome would **be much as** when Christopher Columbus first landed in America, **which** didn't turn out very well for the Native Americans

Read more: http://news.cnet.com/8301-17852_3-20003949-71.html#ixzz1E2gBVWga

What does the *which* mean?

Comment: If you are asking what _which_ generally means, see ["which" vs "what" - what's the exact difference and when should you use one or the other?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-exact-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-th).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a contraction of "I think the outcome would *be much the same as" ...*

The **"which"** refers to the outcome.

Comment: Wrong on the which.

Comment: @jae - Care to elaborate?

Comment: be much the same as the outcome was when

Comment: @Chris: see kiam's answer on that.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase can be interpreted as having an implicit *as* (*as much as* instead of *much as*), and read as

> If aliens ever visit us, I think the outcome would be the same as when Christopher Columbus first landed in America, which didn't turn out very well for the Native Americans.

*Which* is a relative pronoun used to for something previously mentioned; in the example, *which* refers to *when Christopher Columbus first landed in America*.
The sense of the sentence is that the outcome of aliens visiting us would be the same as when Columbus first landed in America: it would not turn out very well for us.

Comment: I don't think "as much as" is what they meant here. As much *what* as when Columbus landed?