# "What/Which word best describes XXX ?"

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Which” vs “what” - what's the difference and when should you use one or the other?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-oth)

Which of the following two phrases is the more correct or are they both acceptable?

> **What** word best describes XXX ?
>
> **Which** word best describes XXX ?

Comment: The use of three X's sound funny.

Answer (score 3):

I would say "which word" if I'm presenting a short list of words, one of which is the correct answer.  In other words, if this question is multichoice.  "Which" often means "choose from a number of options".

I would say "what word" if the question is open-ended; there's no suggested list, and any word in the English language is potentially an answer.

Comment: +1. I'd have said the same as well, but this is a dupe.