# "Which" or "what" for accepting multiple choices from a list

Tags: word-choice, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Which” vs. “what” — what's the difference and when should you use one or the other?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot)

I know that, in the context of radio buttons (the options are limited and they choose one), I should use *which*. For example, *Which is your favorite color?*

( ) blue
( ) green
( ) red

I also suspect that for an unlimited text box, the correct option is *what*. For example, *What is your favorite color?* ________________

My instinct tells me that the same is true for checkboxes. For example, *What colors do you prefer?*

[ ] blue
[ ] green
[ ] red

When they can select multiple answers, I should use *What colors do you prefer?*, not *Which colors do you prefer?*, right?

Answer (score 2):

*Which* is used to choose from a list, contrasting *what*. *Which* can be used for multiple options. In your situation, *which* is correct. However, *what* is also correct, as once the options are presented, it is clear that the choice is to be made from among the list.

Comment: I agree that which is preferable. What would only be logical if it were an open question, i.e. not multiple choice.

Answer (score 1):

I feel the difference is only a matter of style.  That said, I prefer *which* for multiple choice, though I may only choose one.

*What* is right on for the editText.

Comment: FWIW, this may be a better fit on the [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1):

In the real world it doesn't make sense to present a list of choices when asking someone's *favourite* (colour, song, food, whatever). There are many possibilities, and people have varied tastes; unless your list was exceptionally long, the actual "favourite" probably wouldn't even be in it.

As [this Google NGram shows](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What%20is%20your%20favorite%20color,Which%20is%20your%20favorite%20color&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), the standard form is *"What is your favorite color?"* (it's the same pattern with [British spelling](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What%20is%20your%20favourite%20colour,Which%20is%20your%20favourite%20colour&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)). The word *"which"* occurs too rarely to graph in this construction.

But when you ask someone's *preference*, this is often in the context of a limited number of options. As [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What%20color%20do%20you%20prefer,Which%20color%20do%20you%20prefer&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows, *which* and *what* occur equally often before *...color do you prefer?*.

In short, *what* is standard with "open-ended" choices, but *which* always implies specific options...

> "What do you want?" *(really does normally imply you can answer with whatever you want)*.
>
> "Which do you want?" *(always implies your possible responses are limited in some way)*.

In OP's context, only *what* is correct for text input boxes. Where "multiple choice" possibilities are displayed, both *which* and *what* are acceptable - it's just a matter of stylistic choice.