# "Whatever" vs. "Whichever"

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between *whatever* and *whichever*?
I'm curious because to me those two words seem to have very similar meaning.

Here's one question, and the answer is *whatever*, not *whichever*.

> A: Is it OK if we listen to something else?
>   B: Sure. I'll listen to _____ you'd prefer.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Fredrick. What research have you done? In what way did it not answer your question?

Comment: If you can describe the difference between _what_ and _which_, you can describe the difference between  _whatever_ and _whichever_. Try the simpler one before you essay the other.

Comment: @JohnLawler You talk like a native English speaker, but it's not as obvious depending on your native language. Whatever and whichever, for instance, are both translated with "lequel" in French, so, your explanation is good for native English speakers, but not for people learning the language. The answer below gives the "restricted set of options" would make everything clear.

Comment: We have a different SE for people learning the language. We're more interested here in the language as spoken.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The same criteria for choosing between *whichever* and *whatever* apply here as for choosing between *which* and *what*. This is a question that has been asked several times on ELU, including :

["Which" vs. "what" — what's the difference and when should you use one or the other?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot)

In summary, *which* is generally to be preferred when choosing from among a restricted set of options known to both interlocutors. So in the nursery rhyme about the aggressive fish, it is:

*Which finger did it bite?* and not *What finger did it bite?*

In the exchange about music, the answerer is not restricting the choice of music to a limited number of options, so *whatever* is the natural choice.

It is possible, however, to conceive of a context in which *whichever* fits:

> Is it OK if we listen to Blood on the Tracks or the new Van Morrison?
>
> Sure. I'll listen to whichever you'd prefer.

Comment: A bit philosophical perhaps, but all music is still a limited set. As in, there is not an infinite amount of songs. So there is a finite set of choices implied. This would suggest 'whichever' is always applicable.

Comment: @jimt In the universe, all is finite and limited. but the set of choices is obviously more limited and more obvious in 5 fingers than in a nearly unlimited range of choices.

Answer (score 5):

We can think about the W-ever words semantically as the 'W' word + the quantifier 'any'. The trick to understanding these terms is to realize that they apply to any single one of the referents, and at the same time refer to all of the referents.

```
Whatever - Any thing (This could also be every thing)
Whenever - Any time (This could also be 'every time')
Wherever - Any 'where' (Anywhere or everywhere).
Whoever - Anyone (Any person or every person, or sometimes used to refer to a person unknown to the speaker)
Whichever - Any 'which' (Choice between a group or set).
However - Any 'way' (In any manner or way, regardless of how).
```

Basically each one means:

"It does not matter what / when / where etc." OR

"An unknown thing / time / place etc."