# difference between kind and type

Tags: word-choice, etymology, kinship-terms

I somewhat know the difference between **kind** and **type**, but I want to know it in detail so I can be able to use these words in my daily conversation.

Which one of these is correct?

> What **kind** of job is this? / Which **kind** of job is this?

Or

> Which **type** job is this? / What **type** of job is this?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question title does not match your question text, but in any case, you may find the answer in *[“Which” vs. “what” — what's the difference and when should you use one or the other?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413)*

Comment: @choster I think OP's asking about kind versus type.

Answer (score 3):

Both are equally "correct". The difference between them is very slight: to me, "type" implies that you are asking about where the job fits into some classification (which for some reason is known to you both), whereas "kind" does not have that implication, and is asking for any way you might want to characterise the job. But as I said, the difference is very subtle.