# should I use which or what

Tags: meaning

> It doesn't matter what wagon you board; you will love the journey.

In  this sentence do I use *what* or should I say *which*?

Comment: In this sentence, it makes no difference. There is apparently a selection of wagons, so _which_ can work; but _what_ is also OK.

Comment: @Barmar: I call your attention to [John Lawler's comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot#comment489658_3414) to the accepted (and top-rated) answer to that earlier post: *That's in **questions**. Which and what are also used in certain types of relative clauses, and their usage is not simple. So **this is not a duplicate answer for any new question giving examples with non-question uses of which and what.***

Comment: ...the *other* answer simply flags up an incredibly fine distinction that not all speakers would even *recognize*, and which doesn't appear to directly relate to the issue as raised here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That question was pretty general, but now I see that the answers are specific to using the words in questions. I've retracted my close vote. But if you search for **title:what title:which** you'll find quite a few other similar questions. One of them is probably a good duplicate for this.

Comment: @Barmar: The implications of John's (obviously prescient) comment are that we probably *need* multiple questions on ***which, what**.* Perhaps someone will think through how to edit the titles of the two we're focused on right now to make it more obvious exactly what aspects they address. We really do need to make it easier to find dups *and* to make it easier to see which earlier questions we find in our searches are merely "related".

Answer (score 1):

I agree that there is almost no difference between the two words. However, it seems to me that *which* here implies there are several cars to choose. While *what*  might imply difference kinds of cars. Eg.  Sedan,  CRV, SUV etc. Hope it would help you out~

Comment: I think the second implication is only when you say something like *what kind of car*, I don't think it's inherent. You can also say *which kind of car*.

Comment: @Barmar: But OP's context doesn't refer to a *kind of* wagon. Personally, I think William here is effectively making the same fine distinction as [sirmirzo](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/59350/2637) on the earlier question. That's to say ***which*** works better when it refers to ***one** of the available [contextually-established] alternatives*, whereas *[no matter] **what*** tends to imply *whatever, any of all feasible alternatives* (not limited to those which have been contextually established as *the ones from which you may choose*).