# Using "What" or "Which" with superlatives

Tags: word-usage, superlative-degree, which-what, what

Is "**Which is the longest river in the world?**" correct OR "**What is the longest river in the world?**" OR are **both** of these correct?

Please explain **with reasons**. Thanks!

Comment: Which vs What :http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot

Comment: It depends on context. If talking generally, then "what" is correct. But if talking specifically about just "rivers", then "which" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Rivers have names, so use **which**.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.