# Question about what kind of, which~ever, what~ever

Tags: grammaticality

I want to express the following:

1. We made an algorithm
2. The algorithm can be applicable to A system.
3. The A system can have any protocols.

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

### We made an algorithm applicable to A system which routing protocol ever it has.

Comment: No, it is not correct.  Our algorithm is applicable to System A regardless of the protocol being used.  Or Our algorithm for System A is protocol independent.

Comment: Thank you. The second sentence is very concise. May I ask one more question? "Our algorithm is applicable to System A regardless of which kind of protocol is used." is also correct?

Comment: @Danny_Kim - yes. 'which kind of' is quite correct.

Comment: @Jim But equally, *Our algorithm is applicable to System A, whichever/whatever the protocol being used.*

Comment: @Araucaria - That fallutes lower in my book.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot). "What" should be used in this case as there are no choices presented, unless the description of 'A system' and its possible 'routing protocols' are discussed before the sentence.

Comment: I want to write one concise sentence that implies meaning 1~3.