# Two "which"s, two "what"s, or a mix of "which/what"?

Tags: grammar

> {I would say}: **Which** antibiotic works best against **what** type of infection – you need to have that knowledge under your belt.

I myself would use the combination of "which" and "what" in this instance, but do I actually need to use the same interrogative pronouns:

> **Which** antibiotic works best against **which** type of infection – you need to have that knowledge under your belt.
>
> {or}: **What** antibiotic works best against **what** type of infection – you need to have that knowledge under your belt.

These two both sound odd to my ears. I think that the interrogative pronoun "which" usually applies to a **narrower** range of choices than "what" indicates. Here the number of types of infections that I have in mind is quite **large**, so "**what** type of infection" seems a better fit.

And then, we go on to consider **which** antibiotic we should choose from several different (rather **limited**) options against a given infection.

Of course, in an instance like "I can't tell which is which", the two "which"s are the choice by default.

Comment: I'd say that 'what type of infection' more strongly suggests a class of infections than 'which type of infection'. I'd probably use 'Which antibiotics work best against which infections?'

Comment: Related: **“Which” vs. “what” — what's the difference and when should you use one or the other?** https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3413/14666

Answer (score 1):

I have not checked if it's true, but feel that *which* works when you have a closed set and *what* when you don't.

"**Which** antibiotic" because you have a known set of antibiotics to chose from to begin with; "**what** type of infection" because you don't begin with a set of infections but go find out from the wide open field.

OTOH, when just matching antibiotics to infections between two given tables, I would naturally say "**which** antibiotic against **which** infection," not "**what** infection".

Compare:
God knows **what** antibiotic works against **what** infection!

---

**EDIT**:
Found this on the [Trib](http://www.chicagotribune.com/lifestyles/ct-tribu-words-work-which-20101215-story.html) (Heidi Stevens, 2010) citing CMS:

> … the Chicago Manual of Style states that 'which is usually selective or limited,' …