# "What author" wrote this novel?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, which-what

I have read a line in a book

> "**What** friend did you hang out with ?"

and thought it was an error. However , I came across an English textbook that also used the same construction.

> **What** American author wrote a series of books about a 10-year-old girl name Anastasia Krupnik?

Is this correct? Why isn't the interrogative pronoun "who" used instead?

Comment: Are you asking about the interrogative pronoun "what"? Do you want to know why "who" is not used?

Comment: Yes . Why is WHO not used ?

Comment: AmE seems heavily partial to `what` over `which` whenever it can get away with it.

Comment: *Who* could be used—but only if *friend* were removed. *Who friend* is ungrammatical. Alternatively, it could be *Who(m)* ***among*** *your friends*.

Answer (score 5):

English grammar recognizes a distinct "determiner" function that is carried out by certain words that precede a noun. Only a limited set of words can be used as determiners. For example, the pronoun *it* cannot be a determiner, but the definite article *the* can. The word *my* is used as a determiner ("my book") but the word *mine* is used in other contexts ("That book is mine", "Mine has a blue cover").

The word *who* cannot be used as a "determiner", so *"who friend" or *"who American Author" are not valid noun phrases. "Who" would be used in a sentence *without* a following noun, such as "**Who** did you hang out with?" or "**Who** wrote a series of books about a 10-year-old girl name Anastasia Krupnik?"

The word *what* is used as a determiner, and in this function can be used regardless of whether the following noun is animate or inanimate. *Which* can also be used as a determiner with either animate or inanimate nouns; there is a previous question about when to use [*what* and *which*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot).

Answer (score 3):

Think of "What author?" as being short for "**What** *is the name of the* **author**?"

This enables to reduce the relative clause "**that/who** wrote a series of books about…?" to "What author wrote a series of books about…?"

I would prefer replacing "what" with "**Which** author" but I guess it's a question of style.

Comment: Being of a certain age, I too prefer *which*.