# "What methodologies are implemented " VS "Which methodologies are implemented"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Is it correct to write:
"What methodologies are implemented " or "Which methodologies are implemented"?

I did a little research and found both. Is there a rule? I personally think "what" sounds strange, but can't apply anything on it.

For the usage in a paper.

Comment: It might help if you have a look at this question on when to use [which vs what](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot).

Comment: @jimm101 - I would have rather been interested in _why_ there are as many usages of "what methodologies are used" and if it's generally wrong or if there's more behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is plural, *which* is the correct answer.