# What or which before plural noun

Tags: grammatical-number, logic, which-what

Is "What things are safe?", instead of "which things are safe?", grammatical and good usage? Here is an example in a (simplified) context:

> In this formula, we use predicate `Psafe`, which describes what values are safe.
>
> In this formula, we use predicate `Psafe`, which describes which values are safe.

I prefer the latter, while a coauthor prefers the former to avoid repeating the word "which".

FWIW: In the actual text, we already given technical definitions for the collection of "values" and the concept of "safe". And "predicate" is used in the sense from logic — as a property that can be true or false of some subject (here, if `v` is a value then `Psafe(v)` can be true or false).
So `Psafe` are selecting a subcollection of "safe" values across a larger collection of all values.

Comment: (FWIW, I've already found https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3414/71325 and https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59350/71325, but I don't find it very convincing in this case).

Comment: I'm with you here, and if it weren't for the repeat, 'which' would be my firm favourite. But in speaking, more weight / stress is given to the first 'which' (- - ....), so the repeat is a trivial issue. And actually, 'what' sounds a little clumsy here.

Comment: Your coauthor has some erroneous ideas about natural use of English, if he thinks you should avoid repeating ***which*** in such contexts. Native speakers routinely do this without anyone noticing anything unusual (even more so with repeated ***that*** in similar constructions).

Comment: ... Even _FumbleFingers_ can begin to sound almost normal.

Comment: "In this formula, we use predicate Psafe, which describes safe values."

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

In this formula, we use the predicate 'Psafe' which describes the values that are safe.