# What is the right preposition: On/In/At and the right question word: What/Which websites...?

Tags: prepositions, questions, passive-voice, will-future

How do I know which of the following questions is grammatically correct?

1. **On/In/At what** sites will this product be able to be sold?
2. **On/In/At which** sites will this product be able to be sold?
3. **What/Which** sites will this product be able to be sold?

And does it make sense to write "**will this product be able to be sold**"?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer one of your questions? ["Which" vs. "what" — what's the difference and when should you use one or the other?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot) (ELU allows only one question per 'question'.)

Comment: This is three questions in one, all of which have been asked before. Please don't post more than one question at once, and please do search the site before asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Things are said to happen "on" a website. Even within a website items are placed "on" pages. This is consistent with the original concept of a website as being an online publication written in Hyper Text Markup Language or HTML.

Conventional markup is the process used by editors to correct and format printed publications before they are typeset and items in books or other publications are always said to appear "on" a given page.

Information is sometimes said to appear "in" a book, magazine or newspaper but this is because conventional documents have covers which have to be opened before you can see what's "on" the pages. However websites have no covers: as soon as you connect to the site you are presented with a page with information "on" it, thus the normal preposition used in relation to websites is "on".