# Interrogatives and which vs. that

Tags: sentence

The same question is posted on Stack Exchange English Language Learners and I have not heard back from anyone yet.

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> *How would I know what things you think are not going well if you do not say anything?*

The context is that someone said that **things are not going well**.

The other sentence posed to ask the similar question to ask about those things which are not going well is the following:

> *How would I know the things *which/that* you think are not going well if you do not say anything?*

Another formation can be done by the removal of *what* before *things* and the insertion/replacement of *those* before *things*, as showed in the following sentence:

> *How would I know *those* things **which/that** you think are not going well if you do not say anything?*

Comment: Cross-posting questions is frowned upon here. Answers aren't always going to appear instantly so you should wait for a response.

Comment: @KillingTime, making the other person realize about cross-posting without having the willingness to answer the question is also frowned upon.

Comment: Is your question simply whether all three are grammatical? Or are you asking which one would be preferred? More eloquent? Or are you asking about the difference between _which_ and _that_ in relative clauses? It's a bit hard to tell what your specific question is. EL&U asks that each question focus as narrowly as possible on a particular issue.

Comment: There are multiple questions here. The 'How would I know what [/which] things you think are not going well if you do not say anything?' query is answered at at [Which vs what – what's the difference and when should you use one rather than the other?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot).