# "which" vs "that"

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Correct usage of which/that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13269/correct-usage-of-which-that)
>   [When is it appropriate to use 'that' as opposed to 'which'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-that-as-opposed-to-which)

I'm not a native English speaker and I must confess I'm quite confused about when I should use `which` in place of `that` and viceversa.

Is there a particular rule?

For example, let's take this sentence.

> The method returns a `Whois::Answer` instance which essentially looks and behaves like a `String` but it's way more powerful than a string.

Is it `which` correct or should I have used `that`?

A few more examples:

> It also includes a huge set of data parsers which converts a raw registry response into a pure Ruby object.

and

> The only exception to this rule is the `Timeout::Error` exception which is intentionally left unmanaged.