# That vs Which when talking about a subject

Tags: pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it appropriate to use 'that' as opposed to 'which'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-that-as-opposed-to-which)

This is actually the title of a question I just asked a minute ago ::- ). While writing it, I remembered one of my **most terrible dilemmas ever**: when to use "which" and when to use "that"? Even worse, Microsoft Word sometimes forces me to add comas before "which".

Phrase in question:

> What tense to use when writing about an ongoing action in a text which will be published / read in the future

vs

> What tense to use when writing about an ongoing action in a text that will be published / read in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*which* and *that* are both correct.

I don't think you really need our help on this.  You just need to have more confidence in your own writing.  But if you really want to know:

> The cat, which was sitting in the tree, miaowed.

Here, the sub-clause *sitting in the tree* gives you extra information.  The commas around *which was sitting in the tree* show that you could delete the sub-clause, and the sentence would still be valid:

> The cat miaowed.

For this kind of sub-clause, which we call *non-restrictive*, you should use *which*.

Now compare to:

> The cat which was sitting in the tree miaowed.
>
> The cat that was sitting in the tree miaowed.

Here, the sub-clause specifies which cat you are talking about.  If you delete the sub-clause the sentence is no longer valid.  It is called a *restrictive sub-clause*.

In a restrictive sub-clause, *that* and *which* are both fine.  Some of the more prescriptive style guides recommend that you should reserve *which* for restrictive sub-clauses, but that is really just a matter of taste.

MS Word's style checker follows these more prescriptive style guides, so when it sees a *which* it assumes that you are using a non-restrictive sub-clause, and insists that you add commas.  Needless to say, MS Word is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your nicely written and clarifying answer! ::- ).