# 'Which' applied to brute animals

Tags: grammaticality

I found the phrase “... the horse *which* ran was not the horse nor of the age which he was represented to be at the time of entry ...” in a sentence of *Codes, Rules and Regulations of the State of New York 9 Executive (E) - Chapter 1, Subchapter A : State Racing Board Thoroughbred Rules, 4039.19.* [[→](http://www.racing.state.ny.us/Sec4035.1-4039.22.php)]

Is *which* wrong in the phrase above, or is it the exact word as the horse is a brute animal?

To be clear, which is grammatical : "... the horse *which* ran ..." or "... the horse *who*¹ ran ..."?

¹ <sub>See the following nGram for "cat who" (cat: no brute), "dog who" (dog: no brute), "horse who" (horse: brute) and "bull who" (bull: brute).</sub>

[image]

Comment: or 'the horse *that* ran...'?

Comment: I did not added the option you said in your comment as on nyt, for example, I have read "the cat who alerted her owners to carbon monoxide fumes", not " ...the cat that ..."

Comment: ... as the cat is no-brute animal.

Comment: You haven't spent too much time around cats, eh?

Comment: No, generally I am not intersted to the cats.

Comment: @JLG - This is a good answer. Why do not you post that in this way rather than as a comment. Furthermore, as your comment prove, my question have aspects that should not considered as trivial.

Comment: When you say a “brute animal”, do you mean a wild/feral animal?  “Brute” is kind of, I dunno, brutish. With animals, whether one says “it” vs “he/she” depends largely on familiarity; household cats and dogs and such get treated with people-pronouns, but critters whose genders we don’t know tend to be “it”. I’d usually use “cat/dog which/that”, but [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+dog+that%2Cthe+dog+which%2Cthe+dog+who&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) suggests that things like “dog who” are not unheard of, however.

Comment: See this [three-way ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=horse+who%2Cdog+who%2Ccat+who&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for “horse/dog/cat who”.

Comment: An [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=horse+that%2Chorse+which%2Chorse+who%2Cdog+that%2Cdog+which%2Cdog+who%2Ccat+that%2Ccat+which%2Ccat+who&year_start=1880&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=10) for  horse/dog/cat x that/which/who is more informative; it shows *that* being well out in front of *which* or *who* for all three species.

Comment: @jwpat7 You’re certainly correct, but I was still surprised by the *who* frequency.  Aesop has a fable about a fox who lost his tail.  That sounds perfectly natural to me.  Odd. You often find horses with *who*, too, as in “mare who”.

Comment: Note that this sentence sounds awkward at any rate: I don't even know how to interpret *not...nor* without commas. So better not take this as an example of good style—officials are often not very skilled with the pen. This looks like it is meant to sound very formal, but the writer didn't quite know how.

Comment: By brute animals, you seem to mean "animals other than pets."

Comment: The phrase “brute animals” doesn’t actually mean anything in English. The closest would be *brutal*, which has connotations of cruelty.

Comment: @tchrist, incorrect.  Wiktionary's first two senses of adj. *[brute](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brute)* are: "Without reason or intelligence (of animals). [from 15th c.]" and 
"Characteristic of unthinking animals; senseless, unreasoning (of humans). [from 16th c.]".  In my experience, *brute* as applied to animals usually says no more than "without reason or intelligence", *ie* says nothing of cruelty or kindness.

Comment: @jwpat7 I wasn’t familiar with “brute beasts”; it’s not current. The *OED2* gives as its first sense: “1. Of animals: Wanting in reason or understanding; chiefly in phrases ***brute beasts***, ***the brute creation***, = the ‘lower animals’.”  Its second sense is much more common: “2  a. Of human beings, their actions, and attributes: Brute-like, brutish; dull, senseless, stupid; unintelligent, unreasoning, uninstructed; sensual.  b.  Rough, rude, wanting in sensibility.”  I continue not to see what makes a horse or bull “brute”, but a dog or a cat “non-brute”. I do not understand.

Comment: "Brute beast" or "brute animal" is a term that encompasses all animals that are not human beings. It has, however, come to be more associated with large livestock animals (cows, hogs, horses). I don't know anyone who would say a "brute parakeet." It remains in current use at least in [legal proceedings](http://www.courts.state.va.us/opinions/opncavtx/0071102.txt)  (albeit in icky cases).

Answer (score 6):

I agree that *that* sounds best.

To quote *Building English Skills* (McDougall, Littell, and Company):

> The pronouns *which* and *that* also require special attention. Use
>   *that* to introduce adjective clauses that are essential to the sentence. Use *which* to introduce nonessential clauses.
>
> - There is the painting that he loves so much. (*that he loves so much* is essential to the sentence.)
> - The painting, which he loves so much, is not for sale. (Here, the clause is not essential to the sentence.)

(Littell, Joy. "Sentence and Clause." *Building English Skills: Yellow Level*. Evanston, Illinois: McDougal, Littell & Co., 1985. 528. Print.)

In the sentence mentioned, it should be *that*, as the sentence qualifies the horse. It shows that the horse you're referring to is the one *that ran*, perhaps singling it out from a group of other horses that did not. You're not simply describing it, noting that it ran, as you would be were the sentence "The horse, which ran, ...".

Also, a clause containing *which* should be separated by commas: "The horse, which ran, ...", which is not the case for a clause containing *that*: "The horse that ran..."

Comment: Certainly "that" sounds better than anything else, especially if the sentence is uttered instead of written down. It was interesting but slightly surprising to read the excerpt you pasted, because I have not found a similar recommendation in British English texts. Surely "that" cannot be used in non essential clauses, but I don't think that the opposite holds (that is, that we cannot use "which" in essential ones). Would your text argue the same if it were referred to a person, then using "who"?

Comment: @Paola - Sincerely, what do you think of my question and of the difference I referred to brute and no brute animals when we have to choice between "who" and "which"?

Comment: @Carlo_R. I agree with what others said before about this sentence being slightly "oddly worded". As for the relative pronoun, I don't have any problem with it; "that" might be more frequent but "which" is definitely correct. Pets, or animals which are closely connected to someone (for example, a donkey for the person who uses it every day), may be referred to as individuals and thus you could use "him/her", "his/her" and consequently even "who", though it would sound out of place to my ear.

Comment: @Carlo_R. As an afterthought, just consider that we may refer to a male cat as a "tomcat" and a female one as a "she-cat", so nobody would wince if you used "he/she" referring to them. Finally, think of the relation between the Alpine soldier and his mule in Salvatores' film "Mediterraneo". No wonder that in the film the animal would be referred to as a human being, although a mule is rarely a pet.

Comment: @Paola: Yes, the same would apply using *who* as a relative pronoun.

Answer (score 3):

In our veterinary publications, we don't generally use "who" as a pronoun for animals. (In fact, we avoid "his" and "her," too.) Exceptions might be made when the animal is named and the publication's intended audience is the pet owner. I agree with cornbread ninja's comment that the *which* in both places should be *that*. Based on the given excerpt, these appear to be restrictive clauses.

Comment: **You *don’t* have to use “that” just because it’s restrictive!**  That’s a new American heresy, and it’s pretty frankly stupid when you look at the English corpus, where you see restrictive “which” used by plenty of well-respected authors. Use whatever your ear tells you to use.

Comment: Here’s an [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+thing+which%2Cthe+thing+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), and here’s a [book search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20thing%20which%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en). I’m sure you can come up with a lot more.

Comment: @tchrist, can you please give a couple of examples and references? I have some books on my desk that will back me up on preferring *that* over *which* for restrictive (or essential) clauses, but I'd like to see your examples. Thank you.

Comment: Again, this is a relatively new shibboleth that’s mostly only in America, not in Greater Anglophonia. It’s bogus. Did you not chase [my book search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20thing%20which%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en)? “The interpretations of the thingness of the thing which, predominant in the course of Western thought, have long become self-evident and are now in everyday use, may be reduced to three.” “That which the senses perceive is only the thing which has shape... Were the thing which has shape identical with the shape...” There are lots more where that came from.

Comment: @tchrist, do you have a reference book or grammar website you could refer me to? I found several books that say to use *that* for restrictive clauses and *which* for nonrestrictive, but I'm afraid they're all heretical American books, though not all that new: Strunk and White's "The Elements of Style" (p. 59; c 1959), Bernstein's "The Careful Writer" (p. 444; c 1965), Cook's "Line by Line" (p.198; c 1985), "The Associated Press Stylebook" (p. 74, c 1975), and Callihan's "Grammar for Journalists" (p. 117; c 1969). (original copyright dates cited)

Comment: @tchrist: Fowler and many others have long recommended *that* for defining relative clauses, so there is a long and respectable English tradition. Although there is some freedom, as you say, and many good writers have used *which* from time to time, most writers and style guides recommend *that*.

Comment: *Oxford English Grammar* (1996) section 5.9 “Restrictive and non-restrictive relative clauses” on p. 225: “ *Wh*-relatives, such as *which* and *who*, are normally the only relatives used with non-restrictive clauses. … **Restrictive clauses may also be introduced by *wh*-relatives.** … The two types of relatives may co-occur in the same sentence: "[…]tumours *which group slowly* are less radio-sensitive than tumours *that grow rapidly[…]" … "[…]it was part of the anomalous froth now being blown off a boom *that* had run for 10 years *and which* had thrown up the usual number of excesses." …”

Comment: *The Hobbit*, J.R.R. Tolkien: “There is little or no magic about them, except the ordinary everyday sort which helps them to disappear quietly and quickly when large stupid folk like you and me come blundering along, making a noise like elephants which they can hear a mile off.” “He had only just had a sip-in the corner, while the four dwarves sat around the table[…] and the depredations of dragons, and lots of other things which he did not understand[…]” “I see now they must have had a private Side-door which only they knew about.” “[…]also one barrel of ale which was still full.”

Comment: There are thousands more examples where that came from, all from English literature from authors of the highest regard. Must I really continue? I shall, if you insist. The point is that this non-rule is a pure fabulation invented by busybodied nannies with no ear from the language. It is inconsistent with English as it is actually spoken and actually written. It is pure nonsense.

Comment: @Cerberus See my citations.

Comment: @tchrist, nope, I don't insist. Did I ever say you could NEVER use *which* for a restrictive clause. Even Strunk & White say, "The use of *which* for *that* is common in written and spoken language ("Let us now go even unto Bethlehem, and see this thing which is come to pass.") Occasionaly *which* seems preferable to *that*, as in the sentence from the Bible. But it would be a convenience to all if these two pronouns were used with precision. The careful writer, watchful for small conveniences, goes *which*-hunting, removes the defining *whiches*, and by so doing improves his work."

Comment: To conclude, I think in the OP's example sentence, *that* would be preferable to *which* or to *who*.

Comment: @Cerberus Even Fowler, 2nd edition, in which he expounds on his desire to separate *that* from *which*, specifically states on p. 626: “Some there are who follow this principle now; but it would be idle to pretend that it is the practice either of most or of the best writers.” ’Nuff said.

Comment: @tchrist: I was talking about Fowler on the one hand and modern English on the other—not literature from Fowler's time. We all know that *which* used to be more common. I was just showing that there is a respectable tradition recommending *that* (Fowler e.a.), and contending that the majority of modern style guides recommend *that*. This does not mean that *which* is actively condemned by modern style guides: just that they seem to prefer *that*. For that reason, recommending *that* to a learner of English seems sensible, although the validity of *which* also deserves mention.

Comment: This has been a frequent topic over on Language Log. In a [recent post](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2425) under the rubric *Prescriptivist Poppycock* Pullum states: "What is actually true about expert users of English, when they are not being nibbled to death by copy-editing ducks, is that they use both that and which in integrated relative clauses, in proportions that aren't very far away from being 50/50."

Comment: You might also look at our very own @jlawler's http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html which he linked on [this relevant question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-that-as-opposed-to-which)

Answer (score 0):

*Who* sounds wrong, *which* sounds better, *that* sounds best.

Comment: What do you mean with the word "sounds"? Perhaps do 'sounds' and 'grammatical' have the same meaning?

Comment: yeah -- by "sounds" I mean grammaticality..

Comment: Horse people seem to like to use *who* with their horses. Can’t say why. I guess they’re closer to them.

Comment: That sounds like a blanket statement (which it really is).

Comment: @Kris Which statement sounds like a blanket statement?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I see only one statement in the answer. Do you see double? :)