# "that which" used together

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses

When I read essays from Eliot, I find him using "that which" frequently, *e.g.*

> 1. the combination which is the murder of Agamemnon is probably as complex as that which is the voyage of Ulysses.
> 2. A very small part of acting is that which takes place on the stage!
> 3. They belong to a different race. Their crudity is that which was of the Roman, as compared with the Greek, in real life.

I can kind of guess its usage, but I want to know more about this grammar structure. Searching on Google mostly gave me the simple difference between "that" and "which", and some examples using "that which":

> 1. that which we call a rose (from *"Romeo and Juliet")*
> 2. that which we persist in doing

It is a pity that Google search does not direct me to any useful page about "that which".  Can someone explicate its grammar for me?

Comment: Oh look: it’s more restrictive *which*.  Perhaps the *which*-hunters will come ’round and change it to *that that*.  :(

Comment: @tchrist, proud to be a which-hunter. [For others wanting in on his inside joke.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66422/which-applied-to-brute-animals/66425#comment127090_66425) Per Bernstein's "The Careful Writer": "Let it be noted that there are two exceptions to the use of *that* to introduce a defining clause. One is a situation in which the demonstrative *that* and the relative *that* come together, as in this sentence: 'The latent opposition to rearming Germany is as strong as that that has found public expression.' Idiom dictates making it *that which.* "

Comment: @tchrist, ..continuing..."The second exception is a situation in which the relative follows a preposition: for example, *of which,* not *of that.*" (page 446).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The combination of *that which* in the example sentences is fine. The *that* is a pronoun referring back to a noun phrase and the *which* is the relative pronoun used for non-animate antecedents. If we expand the shortest of the OP's example sentences to replace the pronoun *that* with its noun referent, we get:

- A very small part of acting is *acting* which takes place on the stage!

We can see a similar (personal) pronoun / relative pronoun combination in:

- He who hesitates is lost.

Answer (score 5):

"That which" = What

For example;

We feel great admiration and respect for those who gave their lives for this country. Our people will long remember that which they did/ what they did.

Comment: Succinct and clear!

Answer (score 1):

I agree. In this instance, "what" may be more suitable and "approachable". However, "what" does not, in all instances AND grammatically, take the place of "that which". For example: "That which disturbs me, does not necessarily disturb others." VS: "What disturbs me, does not necessarily disturb others". There IS a difference, albeit subtle. IMHO, the first example is much more eloquent than the second, while still comprehensible.

Comment: Hello, Jill. Welcome to the crucible that is ELU. In your two examples, I'd omit the commas; the comma is only licensed (and then contentiously) between subject and verb for very heavy subjects. // And I'd say the only difference between your examples is one of register.