# "Who" as applied to non-human animals

Tags: pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use “who” vs. “that”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/how-to-use-who-vs-that)
>   [‘Which’ applied to brute animals](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66422/which-applied-to-brute-animals)

Is the use of "who", as applied to non-human animals, ever considered grammatically correct? Would it be correct to refer to a cat as "the same cat who I saw yesterday" instead of "the cat that I saw yesterday", or is this considered incorrect?

Comment: As a side-note, I think this grammatical issue might be contentious among some animal rights advocates. :)

Comment: I have also seen phrases like "the person that I saw yesterday" being used in colloquial and informal English, instead of "the person who I saw yesterday".

Comment: @MετάEd This question addresses one specific case of that question, which addresses a much broader issue. Is it still considered a duplicate?

Comment: The answer to the broader question answers your question also. In my view that makes your question useful primarily as a duplicate question (a pointer to the broader question).

Comment: If you want to get technical about it, it should be "the person whom I saw yesterday". But the language doesn't support that anymore. Using "that" instead of "who" is an ancient tradition, and as much as I dislike it, there's nothing that can be done about it. Suck it up and don't use it if you don't like it, but rest assured that others will.

Comment: @MετάEd Two questions are listed as exact duplicates. Which one is the duplicate?

Comment: @Anderson: there are two questions listed as possible duplicates. The language in the box below is "canned," it will read "exact duplicate" even if every voter thought "pretty much the same" would be more accurate. Moreover, it's worth noting that some will vote to close as a duplicate when an _answer_ to a previous question will answer the duplicate question; this is not necessarily restricted to the case where the _question_ is essentially the same. In this case, I think the answers by Tragicomic, JLG, and chaos answer this; if others think there's more to say, they can add something there.

Comment: @user21497 If you want to get historical, not technical.