# How to choose between "which" and "that"?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it appropriate to use 'that' as opposed to 'which'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-that-as-opposed-to-which)

Sentence 1:

> The motorcycles with designs which involve an engine, a shaft and a gearbox, form a significant subset of the product line of BMW.

Sentence 2:

> The motorcycles with designs that involve an engine, a shaft and a gearbox, form a significant subset of the product line of BMW.

Which is more appropriate? And in general, is there a rule of thumb to decide between using "which" and "that"?

Comment: In particular read Robusto's answer in the duplicate above.