# “For clarity” vs. “To make clear”

Tags: differences, infinitives, prepositional-phrases, to-for

Compare:

> **"He modified the sentence for clarity."**

vs

> **"He modified the sentence to make it clear."**

Any difference here?

Comment: What’s your theory?

Comment: my theory is that, after many years I learnt that most of the American people does not know the difference between which and that. Some of them were PhDs, teachers. I wondered if there is a little distinction between those too.

Comment: [*Which* vs. *that*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-that-as-opposed-to-which/96#96) have been covered before. At any rate, if nobody knows the difference between two words, then there *is* no difference between them. Meaning follows usage. If everyone uses "which" to mean "oven", then that's exactly what it means.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Actually I don't care about English. My two american friends proofread a paper I wrote. It was an engineering paper. And an American professor highly criticized how as a non-native speaker I did not know the difference . Then I asked my friends, and they did not know either. I said 'Americans' to point out that its their native language. Its because of irregularity of English. In my native language a 8 year old kid knows perfect grammar, because its regular. As I said, I dont care. I know 4 languages, and English is definitely the 3rd most irregular one.

Comment: @EmmetB - Irregular is right - that was unjust of your professor.  Learning any other language than your birth language is daunting and admirable. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To make it clear" is clearer. "For clarity" is more formal, and best (and most commonly) used with the verb "edited" rather than "modified."

Comment: [Evidence?](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=edited+for+clarity%2Cmodified+for+clarity%2Cedited+to+make+it+clear%2Cmodified+to+make+it+clear&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) It does seem true that "edited for clarity" is most common, but all four possibilities sound fine to me.