# Should it be 'which affect' or 'who affect'?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns

I have this sentence

> Persons performing tasks **which** affect product quality should have appropriate skill and knowledge.

in which I am not sure whether *who* or *which* is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the task which directly affects product quality, not the person; therefore, the correct word would be *which*.

By the way, *affect* should be used in your sample sentence, not *effect*.

From the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/effect), effect (as a verb) means:

> *verb [with object]*:
> cause (something) to happen; bring about
>
> *The prime minister effected many policy changes.*

While [affect](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/affect) means:

> *verb [with object]*: have an effect on; make a difference to
>
> *The dampness began to affect my health.*

Comment: That I got in word when I used "who" in sentence, while using "which" in sentence is showing grammatical error.

Comment: @Sim Microsoft Word might call it an error, but Word's grammar checker is absolutely horrible.

Answer (score 2):

In the phrase "which affect product quality," the correct word is "which," because the phrase describes tasks, not persons.

Comment: That's what I thought, but microsoft word is showing mistake in that, it suggests "that" which I don't want to use.

Comment: @Sim ***PLEASE*** stop thinking that Microsoft Word has the foggiest idea of how to write. It doesn’t. Turn all that crap off and you will be a lot happier.

Comment: So Word suggests *that*, but you are asking if you should use *who*. That makes no sense at all, sorry. Choosing between *tasks that* and *tasks which* is an interesting question, which [has been addressed](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which) many times before, in fact. But no native speaker would ever find themselves choosing between *tasks which* and *tasks who*.

Answer (score 1):

Persons **who** perform tasks **which** effect product quality should have appropriate skill and knowledge.

The sentence in question can be rephrased as above.
I hope it is easier to understand that 'which' is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you intend the relative pronoun to refer to *tasks*. In that case, the relative clause which follows it can be introduced by either *which* or *that*, but not by *who*. *Who* is used only when the antecedent is a person.

The relative clause is of the defining type, which some think can be introduced only by *that* and not by *which*, but they are wrong.