# Relative Clause: 'that' & 'which'

Tags: which-that

Here'are two sentences:

1. It's not beer WHICH destroys people, it's beer WHICH does it to them.
2. It's not beer THAT destroys people, it's beer THAT does it to them.

Pretty weird sentences but they are qoutes from a Russian movie translated into English :)

Which sentence sound more natural? To me both are okay as both, 'that' and 'which', may introduce a restrictive relative clause.

Here's what Oxford says: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/that-or-which

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Is a specific beer mentioned before this sentence? As it stands, there is not enough to go on here.

Comment: No, there isn't. It's just about beer in general and, according to the person who pronounces the phrase, beer doesn't destroy people at all, but it may be even useful. Hopefully, it has become a bit more clear. Sorry for that.

Comment: In that case, these are it-clefts requiring 'that'.

Comment: A more plausible English translation might be: 2'
"It's not beer that destroys the man; beer actually makes the man."

Comment: The one who says that thinks that water destroys the man and beer doesn't. So, if I'd like to be closer to the Russian phrase it would be better to say: It's not beer that destroys the man, it's water. Right?

Comment: And I'll just add that 'which' _is_ possible after an it-cleft, but there needs to be a particularisation: It was John’s book {which/that} got me interested in fungi'. Choosing 'which' here selects the meaning 'John’s book was the one {which/that} got me interested in fungi'.

Comment: #user73.. This sentence doesn't come close in meaning to your original, but is fine grammatically, and fine as regards idiomaticity (how natives actually talk). I'm not sure about whether it's true, though :-)

Comment: Oh! it is close as in russian it sounds like: Губит людей не пиво, губит людей вода which literally means: It's not beer that destroys people, it's water that destroys people. Thank you, anyway! I've never heard of it-clefts before.

Comment: The 'it' involved is just a meaningless filler, to postpone the normal subject. 'It's plain that he's a troublemaker' is far more idiomatic than 'T[he fact t]hat he's a troublemaker is plain'. Contrast 'referential it' in 'Charlesberg. It's the beer that refreshes the whole person.'

Comment: Possible duplicate: [When to use “that” and when to use “which”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which)

Comment: Does it mean that it-cleft is the same as Relative Clause which may be divided into 2 groups: restrictive relative clause and non-restrictive relative clause? But then it says (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/that-or-which) you can use both, 'which' and 'that', with a non-restrictive relative clause which is the case I've mentioned above. Does 'that' just sound better in my case? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As your link said, you can use both since you are not introducing `beer` in your sentence.

But for something like:

> It's not beard which kills them, it's beer; **which** I don't like.

In this sentence, I am introducing a fact that I don't like beer..
so I may not use `that`..

*ps: the sentence is weird, but it serves its purpose.*