# Are the commas right?

Tags: punctuation, orthography, commas, subordinate-clauses

The man, who is standing there, is her ex-husband.  Are these commas needed?
Or is it:

The man who is standing there is her ex-husband.

Comment: Questions that say “Is this right?” without anything supporting them are nothing but proofreading, and therefore off-topic here.  You need to show your the results of your previous research on the matter, and point out why you think yours is somehow a special case where such things do not apply. You have to show what your confusion really is.

Comment: Note also that commas are an orthographic concern, not a grammatical one.

Comment: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/dashes-parentheses-and-commas

Here you should find everything you need to know about this topic.

Comment: It depends on what you mean. If *who is standing there* is intended to identify the man—to make clear which man you are talking about—the commas should **not** be used. 
If *who is standing there* is merely an additional piece of information about a man who is already identified, the commas **should** be used.

Answer (score 2):

If "who is standing there" is a *restrictive clause*--if it provides information that is necessary to distinguish the subject from others of the same type--you don't use commas. This is the scenario you're probably thinking of.

If, on the other hand, the clause merely provides additional but unnecessary information, it is a non-restrictive clause and should be set apart with commas. For example:

> A man just said hello to my colleague. The man, who is standing there, is her ex-husband.

As the subject "the man" has already been distinguished by the first sentence, removing "who is standing there" from the second sentence does not make the subject ambiguous. Therefore, it is a non-restrictive clause, and requires commas.

For more, see [When to use “that” and when to use “which”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which)

Answer (score 0):

Not only are the commas not needed, *who is* may also be removed:

*The man standing there is her ex-husband.*

Answer (score -1):

I think that the sentence can be simplified by getting rid of "who is".

Instead writing the sentence as:
The man standing there is her ex-husband.

But if you are only looking at the current sentence, the commas are not necessary.