# Proper usage of the words "that" vs "which"

Tags: word-usage

usage of "that" vs "which"

Is there an improvement to X "that" or "which" you think should be considered?

Comment: See [When to use “that” and when to use “which”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/).

Comment: That's the right answer to the question the OP should have posted, but didn't. There are any number of differences between _that_ and _which_ -- both of them occur in other constructions frequently -- but the OP never even mentioned relative clauses. Which suggests that the OP would not understand the answer, since it involves recognizing two different types of relative clauses.