# That or which in a sentence

Tags: questions

Should this:

> We believed the issues **which would be on the agenda** were too problematic at the time"

Be like this?

> We believed the issues **that would be on the agenda** were too problematic at the time.

Comment: Please see *[When to use “that” and when to use “which”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78)*

Comment: Since the [relative clause is restrictive, either _that_ or _which_ is correct](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html). If there were commas before and after the relative clause, on the other hand, that would make it non-restrictive, and only _which_ would be correct.

Comment: Note that UK and US usages differ. I am British but I prefer the US rules and always use them myself.

Answer (score -1):

The second sentence is correct in American usage. In the US we use "that" to introduce a restrictive clause and "which" to introduce a nonrestrictive clause. A less wonky way to figure this out is to remember to use "which" only after a comma: "We believed the issues, which would be on the agenda, were too problematic at the time." If adding the comma changes the meaning of your sentence, then skip the commas and use "that."