# Is it grammatically correct to begin a sentence with "Which" (in academic style)?

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style

What references, or your  specific expertise tell about the  permissibility of passages like: "We shall assume that 2x2=5. Which, of course, is not quite correct, but..."

Comment: Dear Dan Bron and  all. Again my question is put on hold. I'm completely at loss and would be EXTREMELY grateful to anybody who will explain me what's wrong with it. I'm desperate, because I REALLY made my best in formulating it.

Comment: The relative pronoun *which*, which is present in your question,  refers directly  to the mathematical equation 2+2=5 the two clauses do not need to be separated by a period. See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which/15216#15216

Comment: Thank you. You are right: the example is ambiguous.  The idea was to refer to the assumption, rather than to the equation

Comment: If you wanted to make it clearer that "which" refers to the assumption, you could say "...., which, of course, is an incorrect assumption".

Comment: Aside from the start of a question (e.g. Which of these expressions are valid?), I don't think it's grammatical to start a sentence with *which* in a formal setting because *which* is a [relative determiner or relative pronoun](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/which).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting a sentence with **which** like that would be [exceedingly rare](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22which%20is%20of%20course%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl).

Either

**...2x2=5 — which is, of course, not quite correct**

or

**...2x2=5, which is, of course, not quite correct**

would do.

Comment: Dear @Tim Romano, could you please reopen the question.  I have reworded it substantially

Comment: In contemporary English we do not start a new sentence with the word "which".  That is not an opinion. That is a fact.  Whether we **could** if we wanted to do so is a separate question.

Comment: I fully agree with you. But, anyway, 5 users put my question on hold as "based on opinions", which spoils my record and endangers my ability to ask questions. That's why I'm asking you to reopen it

Comment: I can only vote to reopen, which I've done.  Your question involves punctuation and typographic/orthographic conventions, which are not *grammatical* rules per se. But if we treat typography as a domain, we can extract the "rule" that which-clauses, even when they refer implicitly to an idea expressed in the main clause, are not placed in a separate  typographic sentence.  **which** is not treated as a demonstrative.

Comment: Which of these sentences is correct? Both. I'm not a native English speaker, so the first sentence of this comment is probably wrong.

Comment: @Trilarion - That use of *which* (in a question, asking for a specific among choices) is completely grammatical.