# Should I use 'which' or 'that' in my sentence?

Tags: clauses

I can imagine this might be a duplicate, but even looking at the questions asked, I'm still not sure when I should use which or that.

I'm uncertain whether or not I should use 'that' or 'which' in my case.

If someone could point out what is the correct use (or even if both can be used), it would be really helpful.

In the following sentence, should it contain 'that' or 'which'?

- *The analysis does not contain a timeframe **that/which**

  specifies the amount of time required 
  for participants to synchronize to a metronome.*

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which

Comment: It’s a free choice between a _wh_-relative and a _that_-relative: _... a timeframe which specifies …_ and _... a timeframe that specifies …_ show no semantic differences, and no syntactic differences other than what follows from "that" not being a pronoun.

Answer (score 4):

The rule for use of *that* and *which* in relative clauses
   (both words have many other uses -- this rule is for relative clauses **only**)  is

- in **restrictive** relative clauses like

  - *the book that he read*, or *the book which he read*, or *the book he read*
    **either** *that* **or** *which* may be used; **or** neither, if the relative pronoun isn't the subject.
- in **nonrestrictive** relative clauses like

  - *the Bible, which he has never read*, or *the Bible, which is on his bedtable*
    **only** *which* may be used, and it may **not** be deleted.

For example, the following sentences are all ungrammatical, with or without *that*:

- **She has memorized the Bible, (that) he has never read.*
- **She provided the Bible, (that) is currently on his bedtable*

Restrictive relative clauses are vastly more common than nonrestrictive relative clauses. So the normal situation is that it doesn't make a difference -- as long as you can identify a relative clause, and as long as you can tell the difference between restrictive and non-restrictive relative clauses.