# Relative pronoun "that" with "the only" in the antecedent

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns, antecedents

I heard "That" should be used after superlative adjectives and other determiners like *all, same, any, none, nothing, only, everything little, much and no*.

But in this sentence

> Those who wish to raise the dignity of human life should try to give
>   civilization that star, to equip the world with **the only** vision **which**
>   can save it from ill will and the crazy competitions which lead
>   thereto.

In this sentence, I think we should use the relative pronoun 'that' instead of 'which'.

Is 'the sentence above' grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use “that” and when to use “which”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which) Some people say *"that" goes with restrictive clauses*, *"which" goes with non-restrictive clauses*, but as the top-rated answer there says, ***that rule is completely bogus***.

Comment: The books tell us that a non-_wh_ type following a nominal with "only" is preferred, but it's not a hard and fast rule.