# When used in a nonrestrictive clause, does “which” have to be the first word?

Tags: which-that, non-restrictive

I understand that “that” is used for restrictive clauses, and that “which” is used for nonrestrictive clauses. However, I’m unsure if the placement of “which” in a nonrestrictive clause changes the rules that govern it. Specifically, if “which” is not the first word after a comma, does it alter the rules of the clause in any way? For instance:

> Henry was a mechanic, a job which requires a keen eye.

I understand that “… a job…” can be removed and the sentence rewritten. However, is it correct in its present form? Or should “which” be replaced with “that”?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use “that” and when to use “which”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which)

Comment: You won't encounter it so often nowadays, but *Henry was a mechanic, **which job** requires a keen eye* is still "syntactically valid" to me.

Comment: It **is** the first word following its antecedent. "A job which requires a keen eye" is a separate constituent, an ascriptive noun phrase (not an appositive one) serving as a supplement. It's within this NP supplement that the relative clause "that/which requires a keen eye" modifies "job".

Comment: I don't think we have a question of correcting the "which" to *that* here (I would.) It looks like the question is whether the word *which* defines the clause as non-restrictive just for showing up (it doesn't) and modifying "mechanic" (it doesn't.)

Answer (score -1):

The answer is "No, but it is probably commoner to use "which" in non-restrictive (descriptive) clauses and "that" in restrictive (defining) clauses."  (I notice that American English seems to do this more often than British English.)

Non-restrictive (descriptive) clauses should be offset by commas; restrictive (defining) clauses are not. However *a job* is in apposition to “*a mechanic*” and is merely descriptive. (This is creates a strange, but grammatical, sentence as everyone knows that being a mechanic is a job.)

Your sentence has several forms:

**Henry was a mechanic**.

**Henry was a mechanic, a job.** (*A job* is in non-restrictive apposition to “mechanic” and the comma is necessary.)

**Henry was a mechanic, a job,**[note the comma] **which requires a keen eye.** (*A job* is still in non-restrictive apposition to “mechanic”* but “which requires a keen eye* now qualifies “mechanic” although it is unclear because of a lack of context as to whether the clause is restrictive or non-restrictive.)

**Henry was a mechanic, a job that requires a keen eye.** *that requires a keen eye* is a restrictive clause and *“a job that requires a keen eye”* is a noun phrase in apposition to "mechanic".

Comment: If whoever voted this down would explain why, I would be grateful.