# That creates or which creates?

Tags: pronouns

"let's make a robot ___ creates a copy of itself"

What would be the right word to use here? That or which?

Comment: Please search the site first to make sure that your question has not already been answered. Check [this link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which-especially-in-relative-clauses) for plenty of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both are correct depending upon the context you are using them. If you have many robots and now, want to make one that creates a copy of itself, you use *that* because you are using a defining clause to distinguish this robot from the others.

You use *which*, when your clause is non-defining as in when you just intend to give a description of the robot.

A defining clause is one that adds something essential to your sentence and your clause definitely does that.

An alternate example: My bike that has a broken seat is in the garage and My bike, which has a broken seat, is in the garage are both correct but the first implies that you have many bikes in your garage.

As a standalone sentence, I think *that* is better because you are not producing robots in bulk.

Reference: [https://www.grammarly.com/blog/which-vs-that/#:~:text=In%20a%20defining%20clause%2C%20use,and%20you%20can%20use%20which](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/which-vs-that/#:%7E:text=In%20a%20defining%20clause%2C%20use,and%20you%20can%20use%20which).

Comment: Both 'that' and 'which' would head defining (restrictive) relative clauses here. Admittedly, there are some traditionalists who would query this. _But all grammarians would agree that **a comma** is needed before the relativiser in a non-restrictive clause._  This is the umpteenth time this subject has been addressed, often with supported answers. ELU desires avoidance of bloat.