# "which" should be "that "?

Tags: which-that

The original text:

> In a few years the small workshop had become a large factory **which** employed seven hundred and twenty-eight people.

Question:
I am wondering whether "which" should be replaced by "that", because this is a restrictive clause. "Which" is often used in non-restrictive clause.

Comment: No: Both are possible. In most restrictive relatives, it's a free choice between a _wh_ relative and a _that_ relative. In non-restrictive relatives only the _wh_ kind are generally found.

Comment: @BillJ If a question is worthy of an answer and not receiving a close vote, please write an answer.

Comment: This is a good question but the best answer is to be found in previous work rather than open a new discussion. See [When to use “that” and when to use “which”, especially in relative clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which-especially-in-relative-clauses)

Comment: Not an answer, but in this case you also have the option of "...a large factory employing seven hundred..."